# font consistency in environment (theorem...) and in general text

Tags: fonts, environments

I am using a template, and it uses the font `\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont{}`, the third font in the code and output, for the text in general.
But this font is not used inside environments, like `Theorem` and so on.
When there is a theorem on a page with a lot of general text, I feel
some inconsistency of fonts.
My question is: Should I change the font inside environments to be the same
as the font used for general text? If so, how to do this correctly?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

This is an example.
We will show the differences.
\begin{thm}
    This is inside the theorem.
\end{thm}

\ \\

\usefont{T1}{cmbr}{m}{n}\selectfont{}
This is an example.
We will show the differences.
\begin{thm}
    This is inside the theorem.
\end{thm}

\ \\

\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont{}
This is an example.
We will show the differences.
\begin{thm}
    This is inside the theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont{}
```

Is just intended for rare one-off access to a font not otherwise set up, it does not change any defaults.

If you want to make bhc the default font family you should use

```
\renewcommand\familydefault{bhc}
```

Also *never* do this:

```
\ \\
```

It will destroy any chance of getting good spacing in the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand\familydefault{bch}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

This is an example.
We will show the differences.
\begin{thm}
    This is inside the theorem.
\end{thm}


This is an example.
We will show the differences.
\begin{thm}
    This is inside the theorem.
\end{thm}


This is an example.
We will show the differences.
\begin{thm}
    This is inside the theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to know why I don't need {T1} {m} {n} when we use \renewcommand\familydefault{bhc}. But I don't know what these mean anyway....

Comment: @user565739  You don't want to change the fact that that you use medium `{m}`, normal shape (`{n}`) fonts in `T1` encoding, you just want to change the family from `cmr` to `bhc` and you don't want to do it in just one place (for which `\usefont` could perhaps be used) You want to change the document default, so you just need to redefine the macro holding the default. That is _all_ the `\renewcommand` does, it doesn't select any font. then `\begin{document}` (and other places) will select the default font to set things up, and that is now defined to be the `bch` setup

Comment: @user565739 and there is no need to `\selectfont{}` with `\usefont` command